# Excel vba: choosing random cell from non-contiguous range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying trying to select a random cell from a non contiguous range but am having issues with the code. I have used this method with contiguous ranges many times with no issues. I am guessing it has to do with how the .Cells property works but I was unable to find anything on this online.

```
Set Corners = Range("Z2, AB2, Z4, AB4")

RandomCell = Int(Rnd * Corners.Cells.Count) + 1
Corners.Cells(RandomCell).Value = "X"
```

How can I alter this to return one of the four elements within the Corners range? As of now it is returning a random cell from either Z2, Z4, Z5, Z6. I would like it to chose between the ranges listed in Corners. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I receive an error if I structure the range command with "" around each cell. I'm not sure if it can be used that way. And I would like to keep in non-contiguous because I do not want it to ever return a middle cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Corners.Areas(RandomCell).Value = "X"
```

as long as they're all single-cell areas within the range

Comment: Thanks! I've never heard of .Areas before but its exactly what was needed.